# How to display iAds only on certain views

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad

I have an iOS Sprite Kit based game that I'm trying to integrate with iAds.

I've been reading through various best practices with iAds and I have a few questions.

My game has 4 states:

1. Main Menu
2. In-game
3. Paused
4. Game over menu

I want to display a banner ad at the top of the screen in every state **EXCEPT** the actual in-game state, as I don't want the banner to interfere with gameplay.

[Apple's best practice's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html) say that

> If the user navigates from a screen of content with a banner view to a
>   screen that does not have a banner view, and *you expect them to be on
>   that screen for a long period of time*, **remove the banner view from
>   the view hierarchy, set its delegate to nil and release it** before
>   transitioning to the new screen of content. More generally, avoid
>   keeping a banner view around when it is invisible to the user.

My problem is that I don't know how long they could be on one of the menus. For example they could click retry within 2 seconds of seeing the game over screen, or they could sit there for 5 minutes looking at their high score.

---

So my question is: in this scenario should I have only 1 ad banner that I just hide, for example using `adBannerView.hidden = YES;` and then unhide when I'm on a screen that should show an ad?

Or should I create a new banner view each time the user enters a state that should show ads? The benefit of this being that there will be an ad shown right away when the user pauses, and there won't be a few second delay before an ad is shown.

Or should I come up with a solution using timers, where an ad will be shown if the user is on an ad supported view for more than 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally just first of all set self.canDisplayBannerAds = true; then like you said above just hide and show the banner when needed. I have done this in a sprite kit game called outer clouds if you want to download it to check the ad load speed its works well. The only bad thing about this way of doing it is that the ads will get recycled more frequently so your fill rate won't truly reflect whats happening. Hope this helps a little